# iOS XMPP check connection to the internet

Tags: ios, xmppframework

i am working on XMPP based application. i want to setup that is user's device is not connected with internet and they try to login in application , then alertview will appear that `you are not connected to internet`. i tried this but did not get success.
Here is my try. what should i have to modify?

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

if (![self connect])
{
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){



        NSLog(@"not connected.");
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a delayed dispatch and then an alert. This code literally doesn't make sense. Also, this isn't the place to check for that connection, you should do it in the ViewController....

Comment: so what i have to do ? i dont how to achive it? i just tried when application run it checks for the internet and currently print log. if internet not avaible..

Comment: I'd assume that if the library works, it's checking for a form of internet (I'm not familiar with this library and typically use apple's sample code for checking internet connection). Does this library only check for local wifi? Are you connected to local wifi? Or are you connected to a cellular network... or nothing? Did you also verify in Safari that you are connected without a password screen or something? You may want to try to verify your results with the Reachability framework/sample code apple has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the internet connection by performing a HEAD request is a very bad way to do what you want. Your user may have to wait for about 60 seconds (a default timeout for http requests) to determine he has no internet connection! This is definitely NOT what user waits for your product to act like!
There is a best way to determine the availability of internet connection - it is a [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) monitoring functions. There is a nice [block-based wrapper](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) for it I highly recommend you to look at.

Comment: thanks for the advise. but what about this warning?`WARNING there have been reports of apps being rejected when Reachability is used in a framework. The only solution to this so far is to rename the class.`

Comment: it is totally fine. the warning is for those who build own framework that uses this class. You can just rename it to whatever you want. My projects use this class and have never been rejected for this reason.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Check internet connectivity
    if(![self connectedToInternet])
    {
        UIAlertView *uiAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Connection Error", @"Connection Error")
                                    message:@"you are not connected to internet"
                                    delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", @"Ok")
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [uiAlertView show];
    }else
    {   //internet connection was connected
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)connectedToInternet
{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error: NULL];

    return ([response statusCode]==200)?YES:NO;
}
```

Comment: thanks bro. it works. i have one more question. this code also check for server timeout? i i am connected to the internet but server will not give response.

Comment: You should never check the availability of internet connection in a way like that! Use [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) instead.

Comment: you can also used [Reachablity](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) or Apple in [Demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability)   I suggest you used from Apple demo.